# How to Implementing bottom navigation bar transaction not to fragment , however to Activity class?

Tags: java, kotlin, android-activity, mobile-application

How to transition to activity instead of a fragment, if I clicked bottom navigation item?

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment3).hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment2).hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_container,fragment1).commit();        //this is fragment

        //this is implementing fragment  
        final BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_bawah);
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                       
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                        active=fragment1;
                      
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_challange:
                        
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                        active=fragment2;
                     
                        break;

                    case R.id.navigation_chat:
                        
                        fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                        active = fragment3;
                      
                        break;

                }
                return true;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Intent` class to start a new activity.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected( MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_related_to_activity:
                Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(), YourActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
            // other cases ...
        }
        return true;

    }
});
```